# Correct delimiter height in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, delimiters, height

When using the `left delimiter` and `right delimiter` options, I am having the problem that their height is not equal to the node they are surrounding.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, matrix}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  withparens/.style = {draw, outer sep=0pt,
    left delimiter=(, right delimiter=),
    align=center},
  withbraces/.style = {draw, outer sep=0pt,
    left delimiter=\{, right delimiter=\},
    align=center}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[withparens] {make};
    \node[right=1.5cm, withparens] {make \\ node};
    \node[right=3.5cm, withparens] {make \\ node \\ higher};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[withbraces] {make};
    \node[right=1.5cm, withbraces] {make \\ node};
    \node[right=3.5cm, withbraces] {make \\ node \\ higher};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image: incorrect delimiter height]

Is the height of the delimiters approximated in some way, which cannot be controlled by the user? Or are they only available in specific heights and the best (nearest) option is chosen?

Comment: why do you use tikz? This are simple tabulars with braces?

Comment: @Herbert: This is just an MWE extracted from a more complex TikZ drawing.

Comment: If you'd like to have the taller delim version instead, you could set `\delimitershortfall=0pt` (maximum space not covered by a delimiter)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a look at the relevant code for `left delimiter` and `right delimiter`, which is located in
`$TEXMF/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex` and called `\tikz@delimiter`.

It places a node left or right of the main node aligned to the lower level, measures the height of the node and then executes:

```
$\left#6\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}\right#7$%
```

where `#6` or `#7` is the delimiter depending on the side (the other is then `.`). Here `#8` is the height of the box. As you can see it uses math code to draw the delimiter. I assume that these are only available in certain sizes and so they don't always fit. There is nothing to configure here. However, it would be possible to redefine the macro in question to scale the delimiter, e.g. using `\resizebox*{!}{#8}{ .. }`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, matrix}

\makeatletter

\def\tikz@delimiter#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \bgroup
    \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name}%
    node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,anchor=#1,at=(\tikz@last@fig@name.#2),#3]
    {%
      {\nullfont\pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#4}}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#5}}}}%
      \delimitershortfall\z@% as suggested by morbusg (maximum space not covered by a delimiter = 0)
      \resizebox*{!}{#8}{$\left#6\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}\right#7$}%
    }
    \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}%
  \egroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  withparens/.style = {draw, outer sep=0pt,
    left delimiter=(, right delimiter=),
    above delimiter=(, below delimiter=),
    align=center},
  withbraces/.style = {draw, outer sep=0pt,
    left delimiter=\{, right delimiter=\},
    above delimiter=\{, below delimiter=\},
    align=center}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[withparens] {make};
    \node[right=1.5cm, withparens] {make \\ node};
    \node[right=3.5cm, withparens] {make \\ node \\ higher};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[withbraces] {make};
    \node[right=1.5cm, withbraces] {make \\ node};
    \node[right=3.5cm, withbraces] {make \\ node \\ higher};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I added the horizontal delimiters as well so you can see that they also work.

Comment: Great! That might be worth to send as a patch to pgf.

Comment: What a great answer! It seems that the horizontal delimiters are now of the perfect length, as are the vertical ones on the smallest nodes. But, the height of the vertical (left and right) delimiters on the higher nodes is still not quite there. Is this an artifact of the drawing code, or is the calculated node height `#8` incorrect?

Comment: See the comment by @morbusg above! Problem solved!

Comment: @Nickolay: I updated my answer now to include morbusg's input. Thanks for pointing me towards it.