# Add Arrow in Timeline in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to figure out the following problem: I have a timeline in LaTex that displays the procedure of a process. The order of two points in that timeline is subject to a random change. To display this graphically, I want to add a double-sided arrow above the two points that looks similar to the \leftrightarrow. So I would need something similar that was asked for here: [Adding underbrace in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/adding-underbrace-in-tikz), but an arrow instead of a brace. 
I am grateful about any help.

EDIT: here is a minimal example of the Code. Above node e and f i would like to add the arrow that signals the randomization.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (13,0);

\foreach \x in {0,2,4,6,8,12,13}
  \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);


\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] (a) {$(i)$} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] (b) {} node[above=3pt] {$(ii)$};
    \draw (4,0)  node[below=3pt]  {$(iii)$} node[above=3pt] (c) {};


\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt](d) {} node[above=3pt] {$(iv)$};
\draw (8,0) node[below=3pt](e) {$(v)$} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw (12,0) node[above=3pt] (f) {$(vi)$} node[below=3pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please post your code? This would help a lot any attempt to give you an answer.

Comment: So instead of `\draw[decoration={..},decorate] (a) -- (b);` you want `\draw[<->] (a) -- (b);` Or are you not using TikZ? Either way, a minimal example with your timeline would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, as your post was migrated here from another [so] site, please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I have edited the original post and added a sample code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you mean an arrow from above the node (e) to above the node (f) just add `\draw[<->] (e.north) -- (f.north);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I show some possibilities:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (13,0);
\foreach \x in {0,2,4,6,8,12,13}
  \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] (a) {$(i)$} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] (b) {} node[above=3pt] {$(ii)$};
\draw (4,0)  node[below=3pt]  {$(iii)$} node[above=3pt] (c) {};
\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt](d) {} node[above=3pt] {$(iv)$};
\draw (8,0) node[below=3pt](e) {$(v)$} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw (12,0) node[above=3pt] (f) {$(vi)$} node[below=3pt] {};
\draw[latex-latex]
  (e.north) -- (f.north);
\draw[latex-latex,blue]
  (e.north) to[bend left] (f.north);
\draw[latex-latex,red]
  (e.north) to[out=60,in=150] (f.north);
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (13,0);
\foreach \x in {0,2,4,6,8,12,13}
  \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] (a) {$(i)$} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] (b) {} node[above=3pt] {$(ii)$};
\draw (4,0)  node[below=3pt]  {$(iii)$} node[above=3pt] (c) {};
\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt](d) {} node[above=3pt] {$(iv)$};
\draw (8,0) node[below=3pt](e) {$(v)$} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw (12,0) node[above=3pt] (f) {$(vi)$} node[below=3pt] {};
\draw[latex-latex]
  (e.north|-f.north) -- (f.north);
\draw[latex-latex,blue]
  (e.north|-f.north) to[bend left] (f.north);
\draw[latex-latex,red]
  (e.north|-f.north) to[out=60,in=120] (f.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]