# How to add a reference for a block in tikzpic

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

How can I add reference to a particular block inside a `tikzpicture`.

For example in my MWE below, I want to add a reference next to work "coil". I tried using `\footfullcite{.}` but it didn't work

MWE ([Adding underbrace in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/adding-underbrace-in-tikz))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,snakes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.3,minimum height=0.6]

\node (wall1) [ground, minimum height=2cm] {};
\draw (wall1.north east) -- (wall1.south east);
\node [draw,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.5cm] (mass) at (2,0) {m};
\node (fix) at (0,0) {};
\draw [
    snake=coil,
    segment amplitude=5pt,
    segment length=5pt
] (wall1.east) -- (mass); 
\draw [
    thick,
    decoration={
        brace,
        mirror,
        raise=0.5cm
    },
    decorate
] (wall1.east) -- (mass) 
node [pos=0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-0.55cm] {coil}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing works inside `tikzpicture`. Footnote are trickier, they need to be separated as `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,snakes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,
  minimum width=0.3,minimum height=0.6]

\node (wall1) [ground, minimum height=2cm] {};
\draw (wall1.north east) -- (wall1.south east);
\node [draw,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.5cm] (mass) at (2,0) {m};
\node (fix) at (0,0) {};
\draw [
    snake=coil,
    segment amplitude=5pt,
    segment length=5pt
] (wall1.east) -- (mass);
\draw [
    thick,
    decoration={
        brace,
        mirror,
        raise=0.5cm
    },
    decorate
] (wall1.east) -- (mass)
node [pos=0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-0.55cm] {coil \cite{coil}\footnotemark};
\end{tikzpicture}
\footnotetext{The footnote}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{coil}The Author, \textit{The Title}, 2016.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]