# Brackets around matrices in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, braces

I'm writing a custom package for labeled matrices using TikZ. I noticed an inconsistency in TikZ. This is best illustrated with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m.west)]
\matrix (m) [draw=white!80!black, 
         left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]}, matrix of math nodes] 
         { 1 & 1 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m.west)]
\matrix (m) [draw=white!80!black,
         left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]}, matrix of math nodes] 
         { 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m.west)]
\matrix (m) [draw=white!80!black, 
         left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]}, matrix of math nodes] 
         { 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Surprisingly (to me at least), this is rendered as follows:

[image]

Clearly, the braces for the single-line matrix are aligned differently from the multi-line matrix. I'd expect the braces to be slightly smaller than the grey box in all cases.

Why is this and, more importantly, how do I remedy this?

**UPDATE 1**: Following @percusse's comment below, the remedy seems to be to add `outer sep=0pt` to the options of each matrix. Now I run into the next problem: I want to control the amount of space between rows. When adding `row sep=0.1em` to each matrix (in addition to `outer sep=0pt`), this is, again surprisingly, rendered as:

[image]

Comment: I can't check what is eating the option right now but the one-liner needs `outer sep=0`. Also you don't need brace decoration for the **brackets** ;) And `black!20` gives you the same color.

Comment: Ah, great! I would never have though of that. About the brackets: what is your suggested way to draw them without brace decoration?

Comment: The delimiters don't need any brace decoration. Try it without the decoration library and the `decoration=brace` options. It will still work.

Comment: @percusse: Then the next question is: why does adding `row sep=0.1em` introduce the same unexpected shift again for the second (two-by-two) matrix?

Comment: Instead `outer sep=0` perhaps `outer ysep=0` is enough

Comment: @Yori Indeed, as I've commented above, something is eating the proper height calculation. It smells like a bug. I hope I'll have time later to read the code to try to understand the cause. Maybe someone else would come up with a fix in the meantime.

Comment: @percusse See update 2 in my question.

Comment: Ah great you found Martin's fix. I'm safe now :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem after hints from @percusse . The reason for the problem is that TeX performs some kind of rounding on the height of the delimiters. This is illustrated by the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 33pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 34pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 35pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 36pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 37pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 38pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 39pt {}}\right]$
$\left[\vcenter{\vbox to 40pt {}}\right]$
\end{document}
```

which is rendered as follows:

[image]

The offending code in PGF is in the file

```
texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex,
```

the following macro is defined:

```
\def\tikz@delimiter#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \bgroup
    \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name}%
    node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,draw=none,fill=none,anchor=#1,at=(\tikz@last@fig@name.#2),#3]
    {%
      {\nullfont\pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#4}}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{#5}}}}%
      $\left#6\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}\right#7$%
    }
    \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}%
  \egroup%
}
```

The first line inside the body of the node calculates the desired height of the delimiter. The second line creates a math environment with left and right delimiters, with the inner body (`\vcenter{\hrule height .5#8 depth .5#8 width0pt}`) being an empty box of the desired height. However, the delimiters placed around this box are not of the correct size. So: in order to draw the brackets properly, I guess we should resort to using TikZ to draw the brackets (i.e., draw the lines "manually"), instead of letting TeX do the work.

But perhaps a better approach is to scale the TeX-generated brackets slightly to match the correct size. Martin Scharrer already implemented this. His code can be found in: [Correct delimiter height in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22801/correct-delimiter-height-in-tikz?rq=1)