# Length of matrix delimiters using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, delimiters, tikz-pic

I'm trying to explain the Sarrus method and to draw the lines between nodes I'm using the `tikz` and `matrix` packages. However, when the delimiters are not parentheses but vertical bars (and also redefining the rows and columns separations) they become too long. I've tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22801/correct-delimiter-height-in-tikz) but it didn't work out.

I would like them to have the same length as the `vmatrix` matrix delimiters that I have written in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{float}

    \begin{document}
        \[
        \det(A) = \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        a & b & c\\
        d & e & f\\
        g & h & i
        \end{vmatrix*}
        \]
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            $ \det(A) =$
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
            baseline=(A-2-1.base), 
            every left delimiter/.style={xshift=.8em},
            every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-.8em},
            ]
            \matrix [
            matrix of math nodes, 
            row sep={0.43cm,between origins}, 
            column sep={0.6cm,between origins},
            left delimiter=|,
            right delimiter=|] (A) 
            {
                a & b & c \\
                d & e & f \\
                g & h & i \\
            };

            \draw[line width=0.6pt] (A-1-1.center) -- (A-3-3.center);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] (A-2-1.center) -- (A-3-2.center) -- (A-1-3.center) -- (A-2-1.center)--cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the (new) `tikzmark` library for that. Then the matrices look (apart from the lines) like twins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \det(A) = \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
    a & b & c\\
    d & e & f\\
    g & h & i
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \]
    \[
    \det(A) = \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
    \tikzmarknode{a}{a} & b & \tikzmarknode{c}{c}\\
    \tikzmarknode{d}{d} & e & f\\
    g & \tikzmarknode{h}{h} & \tikzmarknode{i}{i}
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[line width=0.6pt] (a.center) -- (i.center)
    (d.center) -- (c.center) -- (h.center) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By compiling that code I get the error 'Undefined control sequence \tikzmarknode'. Weird :/

Comment: @Martín Yes, there has been an update of the library last year, in which `\tikzmarknode` was added. If you update your TeX distribution (or download the latest version of the library), you will no longer get this error. (This is why I added "(new)" before `tikzmark`, but yes, "new" is relative.)